# Probability function for taking X (geometric distribution)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

There are chocolate bars from #1-#100. If I want to find chocolate bar # 42, and let X be the number of chocolate bars taken without replacing them until I find #42, then what is the probability function for X?

This is picking chocolate before I get the one I want, so I need a geometric distribution. But when I take a chocolate bar, I don't put it back, so the probability of finding #42 is different every time. So I think the probability is $\sum_{i=100}^{1}\frac{1}{x_i}(1-\frac{1}{x_i})$. How close am I to getting the answer? Also I need to make sure $\sum = 1$ because it's a probability function.

Comment: This is not Geometric distribution, which is WITH replacement. As for the solution to your problem, a hint: consider just 4 or 5 bars in total and you want to find one of them.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I'm not very smart so I don't get the hint...can you explain?

Comment: If your actual question is too hard, try to solve a simpler version of it first.